# ng-class conditional value not getting reflected

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have a list. I want to show the selected object as active. For that I have written the code as below:

**HTML**

```
<li ng-class="{'active' : testObject.selected}" >
    <a ng-click="showApp()">                
        <span>App</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.testObject = {
    selected: false
};

$scope.showApp = function() {  
   $scope.testObject['selected'] = true;
   //my code
}
```

Here, `testObject.selected` is a boolean and I am setting its value (true/false) inside `showApp()` function. It is not working somehow.

Comment: can you post your controller?

Comment: `Object` is a `js` keyword that should be the case

Comment: class name without '' , something like ng-class="{active: testObject.selected}"   check documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: Did you try to add an alter in the showApp function ? Does it show ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues with your code... I copied it into here a plnkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pjNBHvCnju4zs7QTZ87C?p=preview

Are you sure the class of `active` has CSS in it that will be reflected in your view?

Have you verified that the class is actually being added to the element or not via the browser dev tools?

Comment: class is not being added to the element. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Typo in the property name or class name? New scope if this is inside of an ng-repeat (lots of questions/answers about that one)?

Answer (score 0):

If you work with a form, then make sure you have checked your `<form>` element.
Each **required** `<input>` should have binding with a variable via [(ng-model)] (two-way binding is necessary in this case).
I had the same issue and ng-class worked correctly only after these changes.